# Have you ever installed the ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK and ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK Tools via CocoaPods?

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, skmaps

Now, I have an issue with integrating SKMaps iOS SDK and Tools.
I did integrate your SDK and Tools using cocoapods, not manually.
But it's not working.

Here's the screenshot of error I got finally.

[cocoapods directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EGVe.png)

[x86_64 errors I got from building pod.proj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDTqN.png)

Is it possible to integrate SKMaps iOS SDK and Tools via cocoapods?
Or, shall I have to integrate them manually from Demo project that I've downloaded?

I did research on Skobbler developer forums, but no related questions/answers.

**Dear Ando**, I know you are an expert in SKMaps.
Please let me know if you have ever experienced this before.

Hope your kindly support.
Best.

Answer (score 0):

Integration with cocoapods worked fine for me.
Be sure that you opened and are trying to build .xcworkspace file of your project created after you run "pod install".